# Assign rownumber in SQL grouped on value and n rows per rownumber

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to generate a report with 3 rows per page for each order number using the following SQL.
As you can see from the results the fields Actual & Expected do not match up.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
set nocount on
DECLARE @Orders TABLE (Expected int, OrderNumber INT, OrderDetailsNumber int)
Insert into @orders  values (0,1,1)
Insert into @orders  values (0,1,2)
Insert into @orders  values (0,1,3)
Insert into @orders  values (1,1,4)
Insert into @orders  values (2,2,5)
Insert into @orders  values (2,2,6)
Insert into @orders  values (2,2,7)
Insert into @orders  values (3,2,8)
Insert into @orders  values (3,2,9)

select cast(((row_number() over( order by OrderNumber)) -1) /3 as int) as [Actual]
        ,* 
from @orders


Actual      Expected    OrderNumber OrderDetailsNumber
----------- ----------- ----------- ------------------
0           0           1           1
0           0           1           2
0           0           1           3
1           1           1           4
1           2           2           5
1           2           2           6
2           2           2           7
2           3           2           8
2           3           2           9
```

Comment: The columns Actual and Expected cannot match up, because Actual is "actually" (:P) generated using the ROW_NUMBER and OVER functions, while Expected is a column with its own values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, after a couple of edits I have the final answer:

```
 SELECT     DENSE_RANK() OVER (Order BY OrderNumber, floor(RowNumber/3)) - 1 AS Actual,
            Expected,
            OrderNumber,
            OrderDetailsNumber
 FROM
 (
 SELECT     *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER   (
                        PARTITION BY    OrderNumber 
                        ORDER BY        OrderDetailsNumber
                        ) - 1 AS RowNumber
 FROM       @Orders
 ) RowNumberTable
```

Gives the result (with extra rows for testing):

```
Actual               Expected    OrderNumber OrderDetailsNumber
-------------------- ----------- ----------- ------------------
0                           0             1             1
0                           0             1             2
0                           0             1             3
1                           1             1             4
1                           1             1             12
2                           2             2             5
2                           2             2             6
2                           2             2             7
3                           3             2             8
3                           3             2             9
3                           4             2             11
4                           3             2             27
5                           5             3             10
```

This only works where OrderDetailsNumber is unique such that the result is deterministic.

### Edit

I've now got the complete code working, however the dependence on OrderDetailsNumber being in order is very iffy, hopefully you can test and edit as required.

### Edit 2

I've put the 'golfed' version in the main answer.

```
WITH FirstCTE AS
(
    SELECT 
    OrderNumber, 
    OrderDetailsNumber, 
    Expected,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER   (
                        PARTITION BY    OrderNumber 
                        ORDER BY        OrderDetailsNumber
                        ) - 1 AS RowNumber
    FROM @Orders
)
, SecondCTE AS
(
    SELECT OrderDetailsNumber as odn,
    floor(RowNumber/3) as page_for_order_number,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (Order BY OrderNumber, floor(RowNumber/3)) - 1 AS Actual

 FROM FirstCTE
)
SELECT  c2.page_for_order_number,
        c1.RowNumber,
        C2.Actual,
        c1.Expected,
        c1.OrderNumber,
        c1.OrderDetailsNumber
 FROM   FirstCTE AS c1
 INNER JOIN SecondCTE AS c2
 on     c2.odn = c1.OrderDetailsNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

This strikes me as a bit of a hack, but it works...
Divide the row_number() by 3, and use [CEILING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189818%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)to get the smallest integer greater than or equal to the result of that division.

```
select row_number() over( order by OrderNumber) as [Actual],
cast (row_number() over(order by ordernumber) as decimal(5,1)) / 3,
CEILING(cast (row_number() over(order by ordernumber) as decimal(5,1)) / 3)as GRPR,
        * 
from @orders
```

EDIT:  Dang it, can never get results to line up.  The 3rd column in the result set is your "page number".
Which yields:

```
Actual  (No column name)    PG_NBR Expected OrderNumber OrderDetailsNumber
1   0.333333    1   0   1   1
2   0.666666    1   0   1   2
3   1.000000    1   0   1   3
4   1.333333    2   1   1   4
5   1.666666    2   2   2   5
6   2.000000    2   2   2   6
7   2.333333    3   2   2   7
8   2.666666    3   3   2   8
9   3.000000    3   3   2   9
```